# create dataframe from dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In order to iterate a list through a function, I used the following code:

```
tot = {}

for i in list:
    tot["tot{0}".format(i)] = stateagg(i) #previously defined function
```

The output of this is a pandas dictionary, I was wondering if there is a way to output to a dataframe or a way to convert this back to a dataframe.

I have tried

```
pd.Dataframe.from_dict(tot, orient = 'index')
```

which results in the following error:

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

Any help much appreciated.

Edit:
apologies I should've been clearer, the function pulls values out of a dataframe to create the dictionary, the data used isn't in list format. The list is used to pull the values out and aggregate data based on the list.

Comment: Could you please show us a snipped of your dict `tot`. The error you mention often appears if your dict looks like this : `tot = {'a':1}`, It can be solved writting `tot = {'a':[1]}`.

Answer (score 0):

To create a dataframe from list, you can try something as follows

```
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list.items(), columns={"A", "B"})
```

For example

```
my_list = {"Math":25, "Diana":22, "Jhon":30}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_list.items(), columns={"Name", "Age"})
df
    Name    Age
0   Math    25
1   Diana   22
2   Jhon    30
```

Comment: apologies I should've been clearer, the function pulls values out of a dataframe to create the dictionary, the output isn't in list format